# authorization omniauth facebook using devise get error "this app in sandbox mode"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

i implement gem omniauth facebook using devise in rails, i follow this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

but i get error "This app is in sandbox mode. Edit the app configuration at http://developers.facebook.com/apps to make the app publicly visible."

how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: if u have made a app on facebook, open page for that app and  then make it "publicly" visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to apps page for your [facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
2. click on "Edit settings"
3. chose "disabled" for the sandbox mode(currently it will be enable)
4. save your changes using "save changes" button at the bottom.

Comment: then accept the answer and put one upvote, so that others also can get help from this post. Thanks.